# Java web start and SSL. Loading a localhost-ca cert

Tags: java, ssl, java-web-start

I've been working on getting a NASA WorldWind applet working over ssl and have been running into a rather difficult error message.

When I try running the pure webstart applet it throws a "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors" 
And from what I understand, this means that it cannot find a CA for the applet. This doesn't make much sense as both the signing cert and its ca (Localhost.crt and localhost-ca.crt) are in the same keystore, which I have marked as the trust store.

Advice and help on this problem would be greatly appreciated, as I've tried everything I can think of.

Things I've tried:

- Adding the localhost-ca crt to the cacerts file fundamental to the JVM
- Added the truststore to the jlnp file that contains both the localhost crt and the localhost CA
- Ensuring that all required .jar files are signed by the same crt

  - Yes I even downloaded the jogl.jar and all of it's natives onto my PC and resigned them deleting the old META-INF
- Loading the Jnlp file over regular http to make sure it wasn't something with just clicking the webstart (Same error)

Attached is my WWApplet Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <jnlp href="WWJApplet.jnlp" codebase =".">
    <information>
        <title>World Wind Java Applet Demo</title>
        <vendor>NASA</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov"/>
        <description>World Wind Java Applet Demo</description>
        <description kind="short">World Wind Java Applet Demo</description>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
     <resources os="Windows">
       <property name="sun.java2d.noddraw" value="true"/>
     </resources>
     <resources>
        <j2se href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6+" initial-heap-size="512m"
              max-heap-size="512m"/>
        <property name="sun.java2d.noddraw" value="true"/>
        <property name="Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore"        
value="C:\Users\srivera\Documents\Apache-Install\tomcat-owf\certs\keystore.jks"/>
            <property name="Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword" value="password"/>
        <jar href="WorldWindWidget.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="Windworld.jar"/>
        <extension name="jogl" href="jogl.jnlp"/>
     </resources>
     <!-- Width and heigth are overwritten by the surrounding web page -->
     <applet-desc
         name="WWJ Applet"
         main-class="org.me.windworldwidget.WorldWindWidget"
         width="800" height="600">
        <param name="separate_jvm" value="true" />
     </applet-desc>
   </jnlp>
```